# mysql join table select with and without GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    messageId INT,
    threadId INT,
    recipientUserId INT,
    message TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE thread_recipients (
    recipientUserId INT,
    threadId INT
);
```

I want to `SELECT` a specific user's most recent message for each thread from the message table.  I also want to get all the other users that are part of the selected threads from the thread_recipients table.

I thought the following would work:

```
SELECT MAX(m.messageId) AS maxMessageId, m.threadId, m.message 
  FROM messages AS m
    RIGHT JOIN thread_recipients AS tr ON tr.threadId=m.threadId
  WHERE m.recipientUserId='2'
  GROUP BY m.threadId
```

However, due to the `GROUP BY` it only selects one row for each threadId, regardless of the number of users that are part of that thread. Is it even possible to do in one query?

Kind regards to any responders.

Comment: Backticks are for inline code. For [code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), indent the lines with four extra spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting. Table structure should be shown with SQL statements. Since you're asking about just SQL, there's no need to post it as part of some PHP code.

Comment: What's the distinction between `recipientUserId` in `messages` and `thread_recipients`? How are they used?

Comment: I don't understand, nor can I guess, what your schema is here

Answer (score 0):

Oracle solves this simply by using analytic functions:

```
select max(messageId) over (partition by threadId) ...
```

very convenient for calling aggregate functions without a group by clause and fits perfectly for your case.

In MYSQL however, use an inner select to mimic this, but bear in mind they can be heavy on the memory for very large tables.

```
SELECT mm.maxMessageId, m.threadId, m.message 
FROM messages AS m RIGHT JOIN thread_recipients AS tr ON tr.threadId=m.threadId, 
(
   select threadId, max(messageId) as maxMessageId
   from messages group by threadId
) AS mm
WHERE m.recipientUserId=2
  AND m.threadId = mm.threadId
```

Comment: `recipientUserId` is an INT, so no need to put the value `2` into single quotes (the implicit type casting *might* prevent the usage of indexes)

Comment: You are right, I just blindly tried to keep his statement unchanged to emphasize on the change :)

Comment: Thanks @edvaldig... I will give your answer a try... So how would you achieve this on a table with millions of messages?... I am really trying to achieve a message system with a functionality like facebooks... kind regards J

Comment: @jon You could limit the size of the inner query by restricting it to messages with the same recipientUserId. If you do that then I doubt you need to worry about performance so much.